# Dictionary Key Order in Swift 4 JSONEncoder

Tags: json, swift, codable

Is it possible to configure the Swift JSON encoder to use the sort order of the struct properties as the sort order of the dictionary keys in the JSON output? By default it uses some arbitrary (but seemingly not random) order, e.g. ...

```
struct Example: Codable {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let createdAt: Date
  let comments: [String]
}
```

... results in ...

```
"example" : {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Test",
  "comments" : [
    "Comment 1",
    "Comment 2"
  ],
  "createdAt" : 549539643.25327206
}
```

I know that semantically the order doesn't matter, but I'd like to keep it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Not in the order of the struct properties but maybe `let encoder = JSONEncoder(); encoder.outputFormatting = .sortedKeys` is sufficient.

Comment: @vadian just fraction of seconds difference between your comment n my answer :)

Comment: Yes, I know that setting, but I'd really like to preserve the struct order, e.g. having "id" as first property.

Comment: Short story: That's not possible with the synthesized encoder.

Comment: @vadian is right

Answer (score 9):

`JSONEncoder` has `outputFormatting` property, you can do this,

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .sortedKeys
```

I've not tried it, please try and let me know.

Comment: That setting uses lexicographic/alphabetical ordering unfortunately.

Comment: .sortedKeys is also only available starting iOS 11

Comment: Worth noting is that you can mix-and-match different formatting settings like so
```swift
encoder.outputFormatting = [.sortedKeys, .prettyPrinted]
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible at the moment, but there is an open request [JSONEncoder should allow custom key ordering behavior](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7992) for this.

I hit an issue where a service over which I have no control required that the fields be in a specific order - it was a small request so I ended up pre-formatting the json and using interpolation to insert values.

Answer (score 1):

The best (hopefully temporary) solution I've come up with is to use CodingKeys to specify encoded keys using prefixes that are lexicographically in the right order and then remove the prefixes with an editor afterwards.

For example, my struct begins:

```
struct Creature : Codable 
    let name : String
    let size : SizeType
    let type : String
    var cr : String?
    var level : Int?
    let source : String?
    let page : Int?
    ...
```

I then specify the CodingKeys enum as:

```
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case name = "00name", size = "01size", type = "02type",
    cr = "03cr",level = "04level",
    source = "05source", page = "06source",
    templates, alignment, ac, hp, speeds,
```

and use the `.prettyprinted` and `.sortedKeys` `JSONEncoder.OutputFormatting` options to produce this JSON (sample):

> {
>     "00name": "Aboleth",
>     "01size": "L",
>     "02type": "aberration",
>     "03cr": "10",
>     "05source": "MM",
>     "06source": 13,
>     "abilities": [{
>         "name": "str",
>         "value": 21
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "dex",
>         "value": 9
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "con",
>         "value": 15
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "int",
>         "value": 18
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "wis",
>         "value": 15
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "cha",
>         "value": 18
>       }
>     ],
>     "ac": {
>       "ac": 17,

Now I can easily remove "00", "01" etc with an editor. Yes, it's a hack but achieves what I want for now. I suppose one could also write an external (or internal) JSON re-writer, and would have imagined that such exists out there?

Answer (score -1):

Question is about configuring the synthesized encoder... just clarifying it is possible to get fixed order by implementing `encode(to encoder: Encoder)`:

```
struct Example: Codable {
   let id: Int
   let name: String
   let createdAt: Date
   let comments: [String]
}

extension Example {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case createdAt
        case comments
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(createdAt, forKey: .createdAt)
        try container.encode(comments, forKey: .comments)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `CodingKeys` and `container.encode` in my app and the JSON is not stored in the order I encode the values.